# Can I use Aptana V3 (Eclipse) debugger with Marionette/Require/Backbone?

Tags: debugging, marionette, aptana3, requirejs

I have the [Marionette/Require TodoMVC sample](https://github.com/derickbailey/todomvc/tree/marionette/labs/dependency-examples/backbone_marionette_require) imported into Eclipse (Aptana V3) and have breakpoints set, but they never hit.

The non-Marionette/Require version debugs just fine.

I assume this has to do with how things are modularized with Require.js?  Anything I can do so I can debug and not have to go back to console.log?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried the chrome developer tools? you can debug perfectly the re, you can open each file separatly just by reviewing the soruces tab and put breakpoints there

Comment: Firebug or Chrome is a much better debugger then the IDE. Hit F12 to activate.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Backbone Eye (http://dhruvaray.github.io/spa-eye/)!
[Disclaimer : I am the author]

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the client code from the browser like firebug if running client in Firefox.  Or Chrome Dev tool if Chrome is used.

Here are the steps:

- From Eclipse, right click the 'index.html' file
- Goto Run-As menu --> Select JavaScript Web Application
- It will launch Web Browser and load the index.html file and Aptana internal server will be running without you doing anything.
- Browser setting is"Preferences/General/Web Browser"
- Then you can follow the [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to debug if using Firefox and to set breakpoints.